# AmazonRDS, Rails and Android

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm using AmazonRDS and related AWS processes for my rails app. I'm looking to roll out an android application yet the Android AWS SDK only notes supported use for SimpleDB and DynamoDB.

AirBnb presented a case: http://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/airbnb/  in using AWS and they also have robust android and ios apps.

Is there a way to use AmazonRDS as a backend to Android and ios? Or another configuration of AWS to allow for this as AirBnb has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a piece of the puzzle. You would not connect directly from your mobile apps to the data stores, instead you would connect through an API you build using a platform or language of your choice.

Through your API, you could connect to any type of datastore, whether be Amazon RDS (Which is just MySQL, SQL Server or Oracle anyway) SimpleDB, DynamoDB, Riak, Mongo or any other store you feel best fits your application.

Comment: Thank you. I have never done something like that but definitely wish to build if it is the optimal solution. Is there any location for a tutorial or walk-through in order to do so? How does it work into the answer here: http://www.quora.com/Applications/Trying-to-connect-Android-App-to-Ruby-on-Rails/answer/Joseph-Marhee?__snids__=219365844&__nsrc__=1

Comment: Is there any server side language that you have used? If you are familiar with android then you probably have experience with Java which is something that can also be used. There are a number of frameworks for java based web applications.

Comment: Or could I simply use REST for the GET and PUT requests to the Android App, and the server handles the rest...?

Comment: REST is a paradigm, and yes, you would probably designing something that is REST style. But you still need to design an application that will be running on your servers.

Comment: So I need to build a web service to run on the server, that would respond to the API? Correct?

Comment: That is basically it. You can write the service in just about any language.

Comment: Or simply just the API, that will handle the authentication of requests and do what I decide?

Comment: Your API will handle authentication of some kind. This often involves generating some kind of token that is used to sign requests.